# What's wrong in this engine test cell picture from the book 'Ignition'?

Tags: engine, rocket, ignition

This is picture taken from 'Ignition' book by John D Clarke.

> [image]

I am bewildered after seeing picture that I can't find wrong in this picture. I guess this is related to the structure of mach diamonds.

Comment: For those not familiar with this book, it's highly entertaining, very informative, and provide excellent insights into some of the engineering and chemistry challenges that make "rocket science" a cliche.

Comment: It is no jet-engine and there is no afterburner, it is a rocket engine.

Comment: It's a fascinating book. I never believed that formulating fuels and oxidizers could be so difficult...

Comment: Since the error is related to the printing edition, I'd suggest to at least include the problematic edition (paperback? digital? Kindle edition as [commented](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/75424/whats-wrong-in-this-engine-test-cell-picture-from-the-book-ignition#comment198412_75425)?) to make it clearer.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I think there's a mix-up in the labeling of the photo.

Here's the photo and caption from a copy of "Ignition" that I just downloaded:

[image]

Here's the photo and caption from the next page:

[image]

Seen together, those two photos and captions make sense.

Somebody mixed up the images and the captions in the copy you are reading.

Comment: My 2018 third paperback printing matches this answer.

Comment: I can see a few differences in the second picture.

Comment: Just checked my Kindle edition with Amazon's online reader and it does indeed have the two photos switched around on page vi.  Good catch.

Comment: @throx If you report that to Amazon, they'll contact the author/uploader and "suggest" they correct the edit and reupload (which will result in your downloaded copy being corrected next time your device connects).

Comment: @Brian - the tree has moved from centre-right to the far left!

Comment: @BrianDrummond yes there's a car visible in the second picture that wasn't visible in the first.  Not sure why.....

Comment: @ZeissIkon and mean that no copies can be sold and the author loses their income until it is corrected - contact the author directly if possible rather than using Amazon's mechanism.

Comment: I'd suggest to at least add the earliest/known edition (2018 third paperback as [commented](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/75424/whats-wrong-in-this-engine-test-cell-picture-from-the-book-ignition#comment198371_75425)?) of the correct printing to the answer directly to make it clearer.